# Django - How can I do PATCH requests - ModelSerializer, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, http-put, http-patch

I have a `ProfileSerializer` which is a `ModelSerializer`:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data, username=validated_data.get('username'))
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return profile

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.dob = validated_data.get('dob', instance.dob)
        instance.karma = validated_data.get('karma', instance.karma)
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        instance.user.first_name = user_data.get('first_name', instance.user.first_name)
        instance.user.last_name = user_data.get('last_name', instance.user.last_name)
        instance.user.email = user_data.get('email', instance.user.email)
        instance.user.username = instance.username
        new_password = user_data.get('password')
        if new_password:
            instance.user.set_password(new_password)
        instance.user.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

And, I have a view named `DetailProfile` which is a `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`:

```
class DetailProfile(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'username'
```

The problem with this is whenever I do a **PUT** request, I have to send all the fields including password. Now, the password that I obtain from **GET** request is *hashed*. So, If I send the same *hashed* password in **PUT** request, the password is getting replaced with that string (which looks something like this `pbkdf2_sha256$100000$v7HiZeWnhmQj$ftiQyZCjMJ6pa26P5w72wQZvn+goEB94/lKyJ8LeKrM=`).

So, I want to make a **PATCH** request and not send password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just override `put` method and add [`partial`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates) argument, this enable partial update logic:

```
class DetailProfile(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'username'

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True 
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

BTW patch request is also available for `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView`. So if you need PUT and PATCH at the same time you can use them without overriding `put()` method.

Comment: And this should be a function of `ModelSerializer`?

Comment: @SreekarMouli no it's part ov view.

Comment: This might sound silly but, since we override the `put` method, should the request method be `put` or `patch`?

Comment: @SreekarMouli it should be PUT. If you need PATCH you can use `RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` without customizations.